# Modifying Buddypress Registration Page

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am trying to modify the register.php page that comes with buddypress, but none of my changes are reflected on the page.

I have tried to both edit the core and upload a copy in the wordpress/wp-content/themes/(active theme)/buddypress/members/ folder named index-register.php
(also tried register.php)

I have tried all the solutions I have found online, but nothing seems to work.

Update

Here is a list of the things I have tried thus far.

1. editing the core register.php file located at wp-content\plugins\buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members
2. Creating a child theme and putting a register.php and/or an index-register.php file in wp-content\themes(active theme)-child\buddypress\members
3. Putting a register.php and/or an index-register.php in my active theme directory as stated above.

Comment: Can you include some of the basic changes you have tried? And possibly what solutions you have attempted as well. Its a little unclear and need more info to narrow down.

Comment: It seems for me that you are doing it correctly, BuddyPress/members/index-register.php is the correct way to do it, so have done you think that maybe the problem is other? Have you try to modify any other BuddyPress template? It works?

Answer (score 4):

I am able to modify the `register.php` page template by copying the original file to the following directory:

`wp-content\themes\my-theme-name\buddypress\members\register.php`

It looks like you have already tried placing a `register.php` template file in that location, it should work for you there.

Comment: This should be accepted as the right answer! Works like a charm still in 2018